# How do you make it so when two objects collide they go the opposite way?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

There are 5 objects in my program currently moving at either -2 or 2.  If they touch, I want them to go the opposite way of each other, but I can't figure it out exactly.. I have this at the moment

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(Unit1.frame, Unit2.frame)){
    Unit1SideMovement = 2;
    Unit2SideMovement = -2;
}
```

What is a better way to ensure they go the opposite way after touching because some may be coming / re-spawning from the other direction? I have the 10 different possibilities for 1-5 coded the same.

And a small side problem is the "frame" is considered the exact center of it so in order for the collision to even happen they have to be directly on top of each other it seems. So when the images reappear they overlap each other

Answer (score 0):

The first part is simply to negate the current value -

```
Unit1SideMovement = -Unit1SideMovement;
Unit2SideMovement = -Unit2SideMovement;
```

To expand the boundaries of the rectangles for collision testing you can use `CGRectInset` with a negative offset (a negative inset makes the rectangle larger) so you would get -

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(Unit1.frame,-2,-2), CGRectInset(Unit2.frame,-2,-2))){
    Unit1SideMovement = -Unit1SideMovement;
    Unit2SideMovement = -Unit2SideMovement;
}
```

You might need to play around with the inset value to work out what looks best.

Also, as a matter of style, variables and methods should start with a lower case letter and classes with capitals.

Comment: It's still just doing the same thing where it's just going through them and not "bouncing" off at all.

and when i do the second part its telling me "Passing 'int' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect'(aka 'struct CGRect').

Comment: Sorry, I had the arguments in the wrong order.  I have updated.